# How many ways can baskets hold balls?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I’m coding a puzzle-solver, and I need to be able to generate each game state. To do so, I need an algorithm related in some way to combinations but I can’t figure it out. Here is a sample problem that the algorithm needs to be able to solve:

“There are 4 balls and 3 baskets. Each ball must go into a basket and each basket may hold a maximum of 2 balls. List all possible combinations of baskets holding balls. Order does not matter.”

Possibility 1: 2 baskets with 2 balls, 2 baskets with 0 balls OR baskets = [2, 2, 0] *(order does not matter)

Possibility 2: 1 basket with 2 balls, 2 baskets with 1 ball OR baskets = [2, 1, 1] *(order does not matter)

Possibility N-1: ...

Possibility N: ...

Note: [2, 2, 0] and [0, 2, 2] are counted as equal and only one should be produced as a possibility.

To recap, I need a way to find all possibilities for a situation like above; the number of balls and baskets may vary. Please let me know if anything needs to be clarified or if I left something out. Thanks!

Comment: will it always be a maximum of two balls per basket ?

Comment: @WW1 thanks, just updated it. Yes, there is always a maximum of two balls per basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have m baskets and n balls, then there are only valid combinations if $0 \leq n \leq 2*m$. If n is outside of this range, then there are 0 possibilities.

Each of your possibilities is a partition of n with a length of m or less (if the partition has length less than m, pad it with zeroes until it is of length m). Furthermore, only partitions with entries in ${0,1,2}$ are valid.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Partition.html if you are unfamiliar with partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the solutions when there are 8 balls and 10 baskets. Can you see the pattern?

```
2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
2 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
2 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```